# Two way slider or range slider Windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to use a two way slider to get both minimum and maximum value from user. I have edited the template and got two rectangles on the slider but only one responds. On sliding second rectangle the first one is responding instead of second.

[image]

Please tell how to make two way slider work properly.

**Edited Slider Template**

```
<Style x:Key="CustomSlider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Value" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1"              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrack"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrack"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalFill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,10" Fill="#FF75B3C1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFill" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,10" Fill="#FFEE887E">
                            <Rectangle.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 6, 12"/>
                            </Rectangle.Clip>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalCenterElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="12" Fill="#FFBAB9C3">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalCenterElement1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="369,44,0,34" Width="12" Fill="#FFBAB9C3">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneVerticalMargin}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,0,18,0" Width="12"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalFill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,0,18,0" Width="12">
                            <Rectangle.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 12, 6"/>
                            </Rectangle.Clip>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalCenterElement" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Height="12" Margin="12,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Where are the thumbs?

Comment: Please show us the code that moves thumps left and right

Comment: @ChrisW. sir I have added normal slider and edited its template to include two thumbs. The image of slider with thumbs is shown above

Comment: @Ku6opr sir, one thumb is moving by default as per slider functionality. I need code to move second thumb and disable first thumb when the second one is moving

Comment: I see [where you got what you're showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199958/how-to-use-two-way-slider-or-range-slider-in-windows-phone-8) but there's no thumbs in it to facilitate the sliding. Show your current template.